# Make a matplotlib animation, by clf()'ing each frame

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

i am trying to make the simplest matplotlib animation, using `animation.FuncAnimation`. I dont care about efficiency. i do not want to keep track of the plotted lines and update their data (in my desired application this would be annoying), i simply want to erase the plot before animating every frame. i thought somthing like this should work, but its not..

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = Figure()

def updatefig(i):
    clf()
    p = plot(rand(100))
    draw()

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig, range(10))
```

Answer (score 4):

At least this seems to work:

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()

def updatefig(i):
    fig.clear()
    p = plt.plot(np.random.random(100))
    plt.draw()

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig, 10)
anim.save("/tmp/test.mp4", fps=1)
```

The issue with the original code is `Figure` written with a capital F (should be `figure`).

Otherwise, I would suggest not to use the `pylab` style "everything in the same namespace" approach with `matplotlib`. Also, using the object-oriented interface instead of `plt.draw`, `plt.plot`, etc. will save a lot of trouble later on.

Comment: duh! thats embarrasing. however, your code executes without error but does not produce an animation. did you test this?

Comment: Yes, I tested it, and it works - but did not show the save command... It is now edited into the answer.

Comment: thanks. vlc plays resultant avi is just a single frame, but totem works. strange. anyway, i tried to embed this in a ipython notebook using [JSAnimation](https://github.com/jakevdp/JSAnimation), and i does not seem to work.... but i suppose that is a separate question

Comment: I've noticed that VLC has issues playing video files with non-standard FPS, e.g. 1 rather than 25 or 30. So that's probably the reason.